# To get the installed applications cache folders path

Tags: android, caching, path

For some purpose I want the the installed applications cache folders path.Is it possible to get this path ( Of all installed on internal memomary & external memory apps ).Now in my application I am able to get the list of all installed applications and when I am clicking on that then I am able to get the application name & package name of that application.

Answer (score 1):

the path to the cache folder of application is usually looks like

```
SD_CACHE_PATH = "/Android/data/app.package.name/cache/";
```

where app.package.name is the application's package. At least on the SD card it is so. So to reach this folder on SD I use:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + SD_CACHE_PATH
```

to create some file there I use:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + SD_CACHE_PATH, filename);
```